# .vimrc overridden by sys admins settings

Tags: vim, text-editor

I have a mapping in my .vimrc file to map F2 to save a file. Have done this for years. However now the system administrator has decided to override my setting with one of their mappings. If I run :scriptnames I see the order and I know which one is the offending script.

Is there a way to just ignore one startup script? I also tried creating a .vim/after/fixit.vim file which re-did the mapping but that file does not get read.

I know I could ignore all files and just load my .vimrc but I do want some of the administrator's defaults, just not all.

Answer (score 2):

You can only avoid sourcing of a script if it uses the canonical inclusion guard:

```
:if exists('g:loaded_pluginname') | finish | endif
```

But it probably doesn't.

Your idea with `.vim/after/fixit.vim` is a good one (you haven't posted your `:scriptnames` output, so I can't tell for sure), but you need to include the `plugin` subdirectory there, too:

```
 .vim/after/plugin/fixit.vim
```

Finally, as a last resort, you can define an `:autocmd VimEnter` (in your `~/.vimrc`). That autocmd will fire *after* all other initializations, so you can definitely change the offending mapping in there.